# Optimization of a multivariate polynomial - affine in each variable

Tags: polynomials, convex-optimization

I'm trying to maximize a polynomial which has ${n\choose 3}$ variables:
For starters I'm planning to do this for $n=7$.

$\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i<j<k<l\le n}x_{ijk}x_{ikl}+x_{ijl}x_{jkl}-x_{ijk}x_{ijl}-x_{ijl}x_{ikl}-x_{ikl}x_{jkl}-x_{jkl}x_{ijk}+x_{ijk}x_{ijl}x_{ikl}x_{jkl}$

over $\{-1,1\}^{n\choose3}$.

My arguments so far:

Note that this is a discrete set. But since the polynomial is linear in each variable (checked by taking second derivative w.r.t. each variable), we can maximize over the entire cube $[-1,1]^{n\choose3}$ and deduce by working our way from an interior point to a corner by replacing each co-ordinate with a 1 or a -1 depending on which one gives a bigger value. Thus optimizing over a cube will automatically give a maximum on a corner.

This is where I'm stuck.
What else should I do before running an optimization problem (if that)?
Has anyone used Gloptipoly to optimize polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than one variable is fractional, your rounding procedure no longer works since the first rounding affects the second one. Although indeed the value increases in each stage, the greedy approach does not necessarily find the optimal value. Otherwise you might as well start the rounding procedure from a random point.

You have a difficult function (from an optimization perspective), yet only have $2^{35} \approx 34 \cdot 10^9$ feasible points. My suggestion is to compute the objective value for each feasible point.

Since Python is a scripted language, $2^{35}$ could still be a challenge. If you do not want to use a compiled language, look into Numba and @jit. You may have to write out the full polynomial. The following code should solve your problem in a few hours:

```
import itertools
import datetime
from numba import jit

n=7;
subscripts = [(i,j,k) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) for k in range(n) if i<j and j<k]
summation_index = [(i,j,k,l) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) for k in range(n) for l in range(n) if i<j and j<k and k<l]

def phase1():
    print(print_polynomial(summation_index))

def phase2():
    max_value = -float('inf')
    max_x = None
    count = 0
    for x in itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=35):
        count += 1
        value = evaluate_polynomial(x)
        if value>max_value:
            max_value = value
            max_x = x
        if count%1000000 == 0:
            progress= 100 * count / 2**35
            print("{} {:.1f}%".format(datetime.datetime.now(), progress))
    print(max_x,max_value)

def get_x_str(i,j,k):
    return 'x[' + str(subscripts.index((i,j,k))) + ']'

def print_polynomial(summation_index):
    poly = ""
    for idx in summation_index:
        (i,j,k,l) = idx
        xijk = get_x_str(i,j,k)
        xikl = get_x_str(i,k,l)
        xijl = get_x_str(i,j,l)
        xjkl = get_x_str(j,k,l)
        poly += "+ {}*({}-{}-{}+{}*{}*{}) + {}*({}-{}) - {}*{}".format(xijk, xikl, xijl, xjkl, xijl, xikl, xjkl, xijl, xjkl, xikl, xikl, xjkl)
    return poly[2:]

@jit
def evaluate_polynomial(x):
    return 0

# run phase 1, copy the output into evaluate_polynomial, then run phase 2
phase1();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Glad someone has an argument on this. I'm perhaps missing something but doesn't my procedure result in increasing the value of the objective function at each stage?

Comment: Interesting you say that I could compute for each point. But I find this computationally expensive on my machine with python. Do you know of a cheap way to compute this? Actually the function up here is an even function, so if we compute for $2^{34}$ of them it suffices. Still very expensive.

Comment: This gives a bit of hope! Thank you very much! Last line, are you running phase1() or phase 2()?

Comment: @Host-website-on-iPage both sequentially, as the comment suggests. Please thoroughly understand the code before running it.

Comment: Left the programme running. It has taken 22 minutes so far, hasn't made it to 0.1%.

Comment: Looks like it goes up by the %!! Takes a projected 3650 minutes to finish the entire computation. Earlier computation technique would have taken weeks! Thanks a lot for the code and I look forward to the result.

Comment: @Host-website-on-iPage make sure that the code runs flawlessly before running it for that long. My projected runtime with WinPython 3.6.3 on a 5 year old cpu is just 6 hours.

Comment: It did and gave the result needed! However the fact that it should take just 6 hours is something thought-provoking. Mine is Python 2.7 on a CPU that's a little over 4 years old. Does a one-point upgrade like 2.7-to-3.6.3 make Python ten times faster??

Comment: @Host-website-on-iPage Great! I found most of the improvement occured when I went from 3.4 to 3.6, probably due to a change in numba.

Comment: guess it's time for upgrade. I figure that even in your case n=8 will still take over 1435 years. Guess we'll leave this here for now. Good weekend!

Comment: what name do you go by? I understand that you do not want to disclose your personal credentials. So we can take this conversation more discreet in a chatroom. I wouldn't dig into it, but I really really need to acknowledge you in my dissertation. It does not bode well to let your contribution slide!

Comment: @KarthikC that is very generous, but I prefer to remain anonymous.. The offer means more to me than the actual acknowledgment, so don't sweat it.

Comment: Okay @LinAlg... Sure.